# Do something on save of an entry

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, events

if that entry is in a particular section, then I want to do some task.

I can't really find the event docs I need to do that. Everything I've come across has been for Craft 2.

Any steps for a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Craft::$app->elements->on(Elements::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(ElementEvent $e) {

    // Make sure it's an entry.
    if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\Entry) {
        $entry = $event->element;

        // Check if it's in the section you care about
        if ($entry->sectionId == 1) {
            // Do your custom logic
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks Brad - is there a list of events for future ref?

Comment: Not currently... easiest to search the Craft source for `const EVENT_` to see them all.